# Make sure ctypes DLL is called from my extension

Tags: firefox-addon, browser-extension, jsctypes

I have scenario where my extension Javascript loads a native DLL (also built by me). I would like to know inside the native library that my extension's Javascript is making the calls.

I can figure out that the calling process is firefox, but is there anyway that Firefox forwards me information what extension is calling the native part?

Comment: What about adding an argument which is a string. And when you call it you type in a descriptive string? ya manual but it works right? :P

Comment: If you really want some automatic way i think your best bet is to ask at ask.mozilla.org i dont think the current community for firefox-addon tag on stackoverflow currently knows too much ctypes. (missing @nmaier :'( )

Comment: OK. Thanks. I've posted the question but it awaits moderation...So,hopefully someone will answer it.